# WiX Bootstrapper - Install MSI from CustomAction

Tags: c#, .net, wix, custom-action, bootstrapper

I have created a Bootstrapper with WiX. It contains a chain with two MSI-Packages. When it is running, It is calling a .NET-CustomAction which is showing a View (like this sample: http://bryanpjohnston.com/2012/09/28/custom-wix-managed-bootstrapper-application), where the User can choose some settings.

Now, I have to install the first msi only, when the user is choosing a special setting in this view. I am searching now a way to do this. The simplest way would be, that I can run the MSI-Installation from my .NET-class (ViewModel). But how can I access the MSI-Package which is included in the MSI-Bootstrapper and run it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When Burn plans your MSI packages, it will callback with the "requested state" for each package that you can override. To see this attach to the `PlanPackageBegin` event. That event is provided the `PlanPackageBeginEventArgs`. In those event args you will see the `State` field that will tell you what Burn would do for that package by default. You can set that `State` field to any `RequestState` you want.

For example, if the package is absent and you `Plan()` an `LaunchAction.Install` then the `State` would be `RequestState.Present`. Your custom BA code can change that to whatever `RequestState` you want. Thus your UI could say, "I know you think you should install that package but this user unchecked the box that says install the FooWidget so make that package `RequestState.Absent`."

The log file will show you the result of the plan and can be very useful when debugging.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Is there also a way to pass variables from the Bootstrapper to a MSI-Package?

Comment: Yes, see `MsiProperty` element child of `MsiPackage` element.